# DB2 connection string password encryption

Tags: c#, db2, connection-string

I am working on .net application which connect with DB2 ibm.
Connection string used in web.config file is 
 


Client run fortify tools which find vulnerability in code for above mentioned code they mentioned like that there is insecure transport database in connection string.

In c# normal sql server connectivity we can resolve it by passing encrypt=true and TrustServerCertificate=false how we can do it for DB2?

In SQL server case we install TLS1.2 and use third part certificate as we disable self signed certificate.

Comment: Add your code, how you connect to Db2. Are you using SSL/TLS already?

Comment: See Connection Strings : https://www.connectionstrings.com/ibm-db2/

Comment: <Connection Strings>
<add name="db2connection" connection String="Server=e232-sivapa.gze.de:1600";Database=GZSNETBDBS2;CurrentSchema=GEAADV1A;UID=WEBADVTVE;PWD=PWDxxx>
<ConnectionStrings>

Comment: TLS 1.2 is installed at mentioned server and server belong different team

Comment: Which Db2-SERVER platform? ( Db2-for-Z/OS,  Db2-for-i,   Db2-for-Linux/Unix/Windows) .   All 3 platforms support TLS/SSL encrpyption.  But only Db2-for-Z/OS currently supports also certificate-authentication .

Comment: DB2 for windows

Comment: Is the Db2-server already configured to support SSL/TLS (by default it is not) ?  Ask your Db2 DBA (if you have one). Db2 Server on Windows supports SSL/TLS encryption. This is a configuration task and is well documented.  This is not a programming question. When the Db2-server is already configured for TLS, and is a currently-supported version of Db2, then your .net application can use a certificate when connecting to the Db2-database, with the SSLSERVERCERTIFICATE=... attribute and SECURITY=SSL attribute in the connection string.